# Get generic C# Expression based on a property type using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I want to call the following function **FuncToCall** on public properties of some my class:

```
public SomeClass<TEnt, TDto> FuncToCall<TEntProp, TDtoProp>(
    string alias,
    Expression<Func<TEnt, TEntProp>> fromEntity,
    Expression<Func<TDto, TDtoProp>> toDto) 
    { ... body here... }
```

So if I have this class (which is TEnt, TDto) I want to call FuncToCall twice:

```
public class User
    {
        public Guid UserID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
```

1. UserID  - type Guid
2. UserName  - type string

This is my actual code:

```
public static SomeClass<TEnt, TDto> BuildDynamic<TEnt, TDto>(this SomeClass<TEnt, TDto> cmp) where TEnt : class
{
    var properties = typeof(TEnt).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Select(x => new { x.Name, x.PropertyType }).ToList();
    
    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {        
        string propName = prop.Name; // Property name
        Type typ = prop.PropertyType; // Property Type ! Important

        Type funcType = typeof(Expression<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TEnt), typ));

        ParameterExpression paramTEnt = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEnt), "e");
        MemberExpression propTEnt = Expression.Property(paramTEnt, propName);
        Expression<Func<TEnt, Guid>> expTEnt = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEnt, Guid>>(propTEnt, paramTEnt); << see hardcoded Guid


        ParameterExpression paramTDto = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TDto), "r");
        MemberExpression propTDto = Expression.Property(paramTDto, propName);
        Expression<Func<TDto, Guid>> expTDto = Expression.Lambda<Func<TDto, Guid>>(propTDto, paramTDto); << see hardcoded Guid

        cmp.FuncToCall(propName, expTEnt, expTDto);
    }

    return null;
}
```

This is currently working because the Expression<Func<TDto, Guid>> is hardcoded to Guid.

But I want this to be dynamic, to take Guid/String/any type from that property Type (using the Type funcType ?)

Comment: Why does `BuildDynamic` always return null and why do you ignore the return value of `FuncToCall`?

Comment: That code is truncated, I did not want to paste everything here...

Comment: Well if you don't use the return value, `FuncToCall` doesn't have to be generic at all. It can just take in two `string`s instead of two expressions. You need to show the bigger picture, so that `FuncToCall` can be redesigned.

Comment: 1. `FuncToCall` is incorrect because `TEnt` and `TDto` aren't declared. 2 How do you invoke the 2 expressions and use the return values later?

Comment: @shingo `FuncToCall ` is known to be an instance method of `SomeClass<TEnt, TDto>`, so `TEnt` and ``TDto` are generic argument of the class, not the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is basically always the case when dealing with reflection or other dynamically typed content, write as much of the logic as can possibly be written in a method using static typing (with generics as needed):

```
private static (Expression<Func<TEnt, TProperty>> expTEnt, Expression<Func<TDto, TProperty>> expTDto)
    BuildProperties<TEnt, TDto, TProperty>(string propertyName)
{
    var paramTEnt = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEnt), "e");
    var propTEnt = Expression.Property(paramTEnt, propertyName);
    var expTEnt = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEnt, TProperty>>(propTEnt, paramTEnt);

    var paramTDto = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TDto), "r");
    var propTDto = Expression.Property(paramTDto, propertyName);
    var expTDto = Expression.Lambda<Func<TDto, TProperty>>(propTDto, paramTDto);

    return (expTEnt, expTDto);
}
```

And then just call that method using reflection/`dynamic`, so that the dynamic typing is as limited as it can be.

```
public static SomeClass<TEnt, TDto> BuildDynamic<TEnt, TDto>(this SomeClass<TEnt, TDto> cmp) where TEnt : class
{
    var properties = typeof(TEnt).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
        ITuple result = (ITuple)typeof(Program) //replace with your containing type
            .GetMethod(nameof(BuildProperties), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
            .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TEnt), typeof(TDto), prop.PropertyType)
            .Invoke(null, new[] { prop.Name });

        cmp.FuncToCall(prop.Name, (dynamic)result[0], (dynamic)result[1]);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Nice and elegant, thanks.